# How to get the date only from a Python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

Let's say I have the following datetime object:

```
aDateTime = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 26, 12, 30)
```

Now, I only want to extract the date of that object. I tried the following

```
aDateTime.date
```

This gave me the output:

```
<built-in method time of datetime.datetime object at 0x000001FD3A1E85A0>
```

What is the error?

Comment: You have to call the method with parenthesis `aDateTime.date()`

Comment: ...just like you did `datetime.datetime(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `aDateTime.date()` with parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a method in the class use parenthesis

```
aDateTime.date()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
aDateTime = datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 26, 12, 30)
aDateTime.date()

Output --> datetime.date(2020, 2, 26)
```